# Blender actions export to unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, blender

I'm making an fps game in unity and animating in blender. I finished the animations of one gun with multiple actions, but when I export it as an fbx and import it into unity, in the fbx file theres only one animation clip(action) that I selected before the export. So basically I can't export the animation with all the actions into unity, but it works with any other file/projects, how can I fix this?
Also Im a beginner with animations.
If picture is needed I can upload.

Comment: Data that FBX Store: " FBX files store all the data for complete animation scenes. This data includes bones, meshes, lighting, camera, and geometry.". Anything else is outside of file's scope and must be recreated in Unity. If "Actions" were the Animations, they should be there.

Answer (score 0):

Every animation should be exported as .fbx along with the 3D object , you cannot export many animations into one or split them after.

Try this:

-export the fbx object with the animation

-add it into unity files

-press on the fbx

-press CTRL+D on the last triangle component (that is the animation)

I've covered the process here:
https://vimeo.com/710101414